# Why didn't the UA traitor warn the Paranormal Liberation Front of the incoming raid?

Tags: my-hero-academia

The UA Traitor was the reason for both of the League of Villains attacks on UA. From the USJ ambush and the kidnapping on the Pussy Cats' training camp. Presumably, they are a very connected member of the student body or staff and are able to relay information covertly.

With the attack on Jaku Hospital, great care was put into informing the multiple heroes involved in this raid as well as excluding any suspected members of the Liberation from the information chain.

Since the UA traitor cannot have been found out as a villain and was therefore included in the raid, what possible reason could they have for not warning the villain group?

Answer (score 1):

In Universe: Because All Might was the only hero from UA on the raid team. We all know All Might is against the league. But he was the only one from UA in the raid. The raid wasn't revealed to the public until it happened I'm pretty sure.

Out Universe: Creator forgot about the traitor thing. Actually what happened by the way.